# ServiceConnection from Google Admob leaks when quitting Native Application

Tags: android-activity, android-ndk, admob

Whenever I quit my native app, using ANativeActivity_Finish and APP_CMD_DESTROY I get the following error from Google Admob. Where and how do I unregister the admob service connection?

```
2020-01-16 01:06:17.586 19569-19569/com.company.package E/ActivityThread: Activity com.company.package has leaked ServiceConnection gu@1dfd356 that was originally bound here
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.company.package has leaked ServiceConnection gu@1dfd356 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1619)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1511)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1674)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1627)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:698)
        at mc.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@21207004@21207004.283464268.283464268:14)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.d.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@21207004@21207004.283464268.283464268:29)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.c.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@21207004@21207004.283464268.283464268:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.a.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@21207004@21207004.283464268.283464268:3)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at xw.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@21207004@21207004.283464268.283464268:1)
        at xh.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@21207004@21207004.283464268.283464268:7)
        at xx.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@21207004@21207004.283464268.283464268:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

*Note:
There are questions on Stack Overflow which may appear similar, however most are five years old from the time of writing this and refer to a bug in admob, which I assume has been fixed by now.*